# Ansible equivalent of the two commands

Tags: ansible

What is the Ansible equivalent of these two commands? Or should I just use `command`?

```
 sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb
> ```

```
- apt:
    deb: <file>.deb
  become: yes
```

---

> ```
> sudo apt-get install -f
> ```

No equivalent.

```
- command: apt-get install -f
  become: yes
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. The only problem it gives me a warning for the 2nd command. [WARNING]: Consider using apt module rather than running apt-get

Comment: Which is what the warnings are for. They are not problems, they convey information. And Ansible does not check what you do with `apt-get` it just notices you use it.